# XML Parsing Error: A string literal was expected, but no quote character was found

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my xml string:

```
<ROOT>  
    <APPLICANT_CURRENT_ADDRESS SLNO=\"0\" EVENT_CD=\"0\" 
         HOUSENUMBER=\"90 abc\" STREETNAME=\"fghdfh\" 
         COLONYLOCALITYAREA=\"fghfgh\" VILLAGETOWNCITY=\"fghdfh\" 
         TEHSILBLOCKMANDAL=\"dfhdfh\" COUNTRY=\"12\" STATE=\"40\" 
         DISTRICT=\"18425\" POLICESTATION=\"18677\" PINCODE=\"545454\" 
         ADDRESSTYPE=\"6\" REFTYPE=\"6\" /> 
</ROOT>
```

I am sending this as an xmlDoc to the database and there I am reading this using `OpenXml(...)`.

I am getting this error when I am trying to execute the stored procedure which contains the mechanism (using `OpenXml(...)` method) to read the xmlDoc. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backslashes from your XML for the attributes.

Comment: I have done that already and it's working by doing it but I am bound to send this data as it is. Is there any other workaround beside what you have suggested?